# Restrict css grid row to a specific number of items

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr)); 
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

article {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

article:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #55BBE9;
}

article:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #afbe29;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
  <article>7</article>
  <article>8</article>
  <article>9</article>
</main>
```

In the above example how can I restrict each row to have only 3 `article` panes, without setting a `max-width`? Note that I still want the responsiveness. It's just that when I expand my browser window, I don't want panes 4, 5, 6 etc. to snap up to the first row.

Comment: I'd suggest use Bootstrap's grid, rather than trying to write your own.

Comment: @DanielWilliams sometimes you don't want/need Bootstrap, similar to not wanting jQuery all the time. Not that your suggestion is completely invalid, mind :)

Comment: and why you cannot set max-width? it seems a good solution

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set grid-template-columns to auto for each column you want.
Screen sizes of 576px or smaller will convert to a single column:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}

article {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

article:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #55BBE9;
}

article:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #afbe29;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
  <article>7</article>
  <article>8</article>
  <article>9</article>
</main>
```

Comment: Would you then use media queries for 1-col mobile layout?

Comment: That's exactly what I would do: grid-template-columns auto; A single auto will tell the browser to just use 1 column.

Comment: I am not sure how this answer the question, where is the responsive part here and the 300px as max value?

Comment: Ok, I've included a media query for 576px. 300px is too small to demo on this site.